# Ansible can't make catkin workspace

Tags: ansible, ros

I have Ansible setting up a few Raspberry Pi's with ROS. ROS installs fine but ansible doesn't let me run catkin_make:

```
fatal: [100.100.100.119]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws; catkin_make", "delta": "0:00:00.012524", "end": "2019-09-23 13:47:24.918048", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-09-23 13:47:24.905524", "stderr": "/bin/bash: catkin_make: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/bash: catkin_make: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Here is my playbook:

```
  - name: make Catkin folders
    file:
      path: "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src"
      state: directory
      owner: ubuntu
      group: ubuntu
      mode: '0775'
    tags:
      - untested
  - name: Clone Git into Catkin Folder
    shell: cd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src; git clone https://github.com/xxxxx
    become_user: ubuntu
    tags:
      - untested
  - name: Add bashrc
    shell: echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
    become_user: ubuntu
    tags:
      - untested
  - name: Load new ROS env
    shell: cd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws; source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
    become_user: ubuntu
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
    tags:
      - untested
  - name: Catkin Make
    shell: cd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws; catkin_make
    become_user: ubuntu
    tags:
      - untested
```

if I login after running the playbook until it fails and manually run catkin_make it works fine, i'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

> "/bin/bash: catkin_make: command not found"

Well this is self explanatory: that means the command is not in the path of your user at the time you try to launch it.

## Longer answer

I have to take a guess here but from what I see, I beleive the path to `catkin_make` is set in your `.bashrc` file when you add the line `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`. If I'm right, see below why it does not work your way.

But first, there are several errors / bad practices in your playbook that you should fix.

1. You are using `cd XXX` in your `shell` tasks while you should use the `chdir` arg instead like in the following demo task:

```
- name: do something in shell
  shell: do_something
  args:
    chdir: /home/my/user
```

2. Your are using `shell` for operations that have existing ansible modules which are safer and idempotent. For example, you can use [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) to add a line to a file or [`git`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html) to clone a git repository.
3. You are sourcing your [.bashrc] on its own in a `shell` task without launching any other command. This will not do anything. Everything is lost as soon as the task is finished.

From all the above recos this is what I would try. Only the last task here really fixes your problem (if my guess was right):

```
  - name: make Catkin folders
    file:
      path: "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src"
      state: directory
      owner: ubuntu
      group: ubuntu
      mode: '0775'
    tags:
      - untested

  - name: Clone Git into Catkin Folder
    git:
      repo: https://github.com/xxxxx
      dest: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
    become_user: ubuntu
    tags:
      - untested

  - name: Add bashrc
    lineinfile:
      path: /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
      line: source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
    become_user: ubuntu
    tags:
      - untested

  - name: Catkin Make with env loaded
    shell: |-
      source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
      catkin_make
    become_user: ubuntu
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
      chdir: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
    tags:
      - untested
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really nice of you to give a helping hand! I've ran the updated playbook but with no success, exactly the same error. Good points though! I'll keep on trying things.

Comment: `which catkin_make` on your machine will tell your where your bin is. `echo $PATH` will tell you where your current shell looks for binaries. Find out where the path is et when you log in manually so you can reproduce in ansible. In case the bin is in the current dir, just call it relave with `./catkin_make`. And if you don't have other choice, call it with the absolute path: `/path/to/folder/where/is/catkin_make`

Comment: @IbrahimElfaramawy: I just rejected your edit as it is an attempt to answer to your own question. Add this as your own answer (and eventually cite mine if it makes sense).